# rounding numbers with custom threshold

Tags: matlab, rounding

I want to be able to 'round' a number up if it's passed a threshold (not 0.5) and otherwise round down.

here is some crappy code I came up with. Is there a built in function in matlab for this, or a more elegant solution (vectorized maybe)?

```
function [ rounded_numbers ] = custom_round( input_numbers, threshold )
%CUSTOM_ROUND rounds between 0 and 1 with threshold threshold

  [input_rows, input_cols] = size(input_numbers);
  rounded_numbers = zeros(input_rows, input_cols);

  for i = 1:length(input_numbers)
    if input_numbers(i) > threshold
      rounded_numbers(i) = 1;
    else
      rounded_numbers(i) = 0;
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution where we round away from zero if the number has passed a threshold

```
in = [0.2,-3.3,4.1];
th = 0.2;

%# get the fractional part of the number
frac = mod(in,1); %# positive for negative in

%# find the sign so we know whether to round
%# to plus or minus inf
sig = sign(in);

%# identify which way to round
upIdx = frac>th; %# at threshold, we round down

%# round towards inf if up
out = abs(in);
out(upIdx) = ceil(out(upIdx));
out(~upIdx) = floor(out(~upIdx));
%# re-set the sign
out= out.*sig
out =
 0    -4     4
```

Note: If the numbers are only between 0 and 1, it's even easier:

```
%# this does exactly what your code does
out = double(in>th);
```

Comment: @waspinator: Always glad to help out :P

Answer (score 14):

just use

```
round(x - treshold + 0.5)
```

test case:

```
>> x = -10:0.3:10
ans =
    -2   -1.7  -1.4  -1.1  -0.8  -0.5  -0.2  0.1    0.4   0.7    1    1.3   1.6   1.9


>> treshold = 0.8; % round everything up for which holds mod(x,1) >= treshold
>> y = round(x-treshold+0.5)

ans =
    -2    -2    -2    -1    -1    -1    -1     0     0     0     1     1     1     2
```

negative numbers are also rounded correctly, except on the boundary: -0.8 gets rounded to -1 instead of 0, but that's the same behaviour as round normally has: round(-0.5) returns -1

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any numbers, not just between 0 and 1. The threshold must be in the range [0,1).

I haven't tested with negative numbers.

```
function [result] = custom_round( num, threshold )

if ( threshold < 0 ) || ( threshold >= 1 )
  error( 'threshold input must be in the range [0,1)' );
end

fractional = num - floor( num );
idx1 = fractional > threshold;
idx2 = fractional <= threshold;
difference = 1 - fractional;
result = num + ( difference .* idx1 ) - ( fractional .* idx2 );

end
```

Tests

```
>> custom_round( [0.25 0.5 0.75 1], 0.3 )
ans =
     0     1     1     1

>> custom_round( [0.25 0.5 0.75 1], 0.8 )
ans =
     0     0     0     1

>> custom_round( [10.25 10.5 10.75 11], 0.8 )
ans =
    10    10    10    11
```

Comment: The risk here is that the output may not be integers, which is what you'd expect when you round.